# MatLab: plot solution curves inside for loop

Tags: matlab, plot, ode

I am doing some exercises on solving systems of differential equations. I wanted to plot many solution curves on the same figure so I made a for loop:

```
for i=0:6
[t, x] = ode45(@exc_345, [-4 4], [-i i]);
hold on
plot(x(:,1),x(:,2));
hold off
end
```

It worked but now I saw that it is not "correct": the hold on and hold off commands would have to be out of the loop. Why does it work anyway? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works because each `hold off` is followed by the `hold on` of the next iteration. Since nothing is plotted while in the `hold off` state, no plot is actually removed. Each new plot is done while in `hold on` state, so it gets added to the figure.